# Are ground crews at danger for radiation from WX radar?

Tags: weather, radar

I am under the impression that the radiation from a weather radar on the nose/wing of aircraft can cause enough radiation to render ground workers sterile/cause cellular damage if the pilot forgets to turn off the radar.

I know most pilots follow a checklist and probably turn it off...but what if one didn't turn it off and a person was marshalling the plane in standing close to the nose of the aircraft?

Comment: We had rampers complain of burning sensations from time to time. Management concluded that certain pilots were leaving their radar on all the way through shutdown. Stands to reason as the radome was about face level and we were marshalled to within a few feet of the rampers.

Comment: @RonBeyer I don't think this is an exact duplicate. The suggested dupe is primarily concerned about regulations. This is more concerned about the harmful effects of not following rules/regs.

Comment: You may be mistaking electromagnetic radiation from radar with atomic radiation that originates in atomic nuclei.  Radar waves are long wavelength photons.  Physical effects would be similar to microwave oven radiation, which, as already noted, can cause tissue warming.  Atomic radiation is bits of atomic nuclei which can cause all sorts of tissue damage, including DNA mutations and serious long term health damage.  They are not the same thing.

Comment: I agree with @Notts90